# Unable to modify Ad Creative URL tags using Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have been facing an issue while updating Ad Creative URL tags.

I knew that we can't update URL tags for already existing Ad Creative.

So, I tried to clone existing one with modified URL tags and tried to remove old one but deleting create issues and now I'm getting this error.

> You cannot delete this creative because it is currently in use for
>   existing adgroups

Tried to change ad status to "DELETED" but that also don't works. Also, tried to change the Ad status to "PAUSED" but no luck at all. Even API don't update Ad status.

Anyone, please guide me what to do to resolve this? Or any other way through which I can update Ad Creative URL tags?

I am using PHP SDK and following this [FB documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative).
I have all required permissions for my application and also they are approved by FB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully did this by following these steps

1. Create new Ad Creative with required values
2. Assign this new Ad Creative to the "Ad" to which old Ad Creative was attached

Following is the PHP code I used to fix this issue.

```
$newObj = new AdCreative(null, 'act_account_id');
    $newData = [];
    $fields = [
        AdCreativeFields::NAME,
        AdCreativeFields::TITLE,
        AdCreativeFields::BODY,
        AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_URL,
        AdCreativeFields::LINK_URL,
        AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_HASH,
        AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_ID,
        AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC,
        AdCreativeFields::URL_TAGS,
    ];
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $value = $oldAdCreative->{$field};
        if(isset($newValues[$field])){
            $value = $newValues[$field];
        }
        $newData[$field] = $value;
    }
    $newObj->setData($newData);
    $newObj->create();

    // Assigning New Creative ID to Ad
    $ad = new Ad($adId);
    $ad->update(array(
        'creative' => ['creative_id' => $newObj->{AdCreativeFields::ID}],
        'redownload' => true,
    ));
```

Done.

Comment: what about deleting the old adCreative from the ad?

Comment: Where is $newValues initialised?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am doing to get it working, still there are couple of issues, but this work most type of ads:

```
public function appendAdSetIdsToCreatives($fbAccountId, $adsetIds, $creativeIds, $fullSync = false, $dryRun = false)
{
    $urlTagArray = [];
    $attempts = 0;
    Cursor::setDefaultUseImplicitFetch(true);
    $account = new AdAccount('act_' . $fbAccountId);
    $params['limit'] = 1000;
    $params[AdFields::EFFECTIVE_STATUS] = array(AdEffectiveStatusValues::ACTIVE, AdEffectiveStatusValues::PENDING_BILLING_INFO, AdEffectiveStatusValues::PENDING_REVIEW, AdEffectiveStatusValues::PREAPPROVED);

    if (!$fullSync) {
        $params['updated_since'] = Carbon::now()->subDay()->timestamp;
    }
    if (!empty($adsetIds)) {
        $params[AdFields::ADSET_ID] = $adsetIds;
    }
    $updateCount = 0;
    $skipCount = 0;
    $exception = null;
    do {
        try {
            $cursor = $account->getAds(array(AdFields::ID, AdFields::NAME, AdFields::ADSET_ID, AdFields::CREATIVE, AdFields::STATUS, AdFields::EFFECTIVE_STATUS), $params);
            foreach ($cursor as $ad) {
                //If adset specified in command, ignore if ad not belongs to specified adset
                if (!empty($adsetIds) && !in_array($ad->adset_id, $adsetIds)) {
                    continue;
                }
                foreach ($ad->creative as $creativeId) {
                    if(!empty($creativeIds) && !in_array($creativeId, $creativeIds)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $creativeParams = ['id' => $creativeId];
                    $creativeCursor = $ad->getAdCreatives(array(
                        AdCreativeFields::ACCOUNT_ID,
                        AdCreativeFields::ACTOR_ID,
                        AdCreativeFields::ADLABELS,
                        AdCreativeFields::APPLINK_TREATMENT,
                        AdCreativeFields::BODY,
                        AdCreativeFields::CALL_TO_ACTION_TYPE,
                        AdCreativeFields::EFFECTIVE_INSTAGRAM_STORY_ID,
                        AdCreativeFields::EFFECTIVE_OBJECT_STORY_ID,
                        AdCreativeFields::ID,
                        AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_CROPS,
                        AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_HASH,
                        AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_URL,
                        AdCreativeFields::INSTAGRAM_ACTOR_ID,
                        AdCreativeFields::INSTAGRAM_PERMALINK_URL,
                        AdCreativeFields::INSTAGRAM_STORY_ID,
                        AdCreativeFields::LINK_OG_ID,
                        AdCreativeFields::LINK_URL,
                        AdCreativeFields::NAME,
                        AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_ID,
                        AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_ID,
                        AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC,
                        AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_TYPE,
                        AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_URL,
                        AdCreativeFields::PLATFORM_CUSTOMIZATIONS,
                        AdCreativeFields::PRODUCT_SET_ID,
                        AdCreativeFields::STATUS,
                        AdCreativeFields::TEMPLATE_URL,
                        AdCreativeFields::TEMPLATE_URL_SPEC,
                        AdCreativeFields::THUMBNAIL_URL,
                        AdCreativeFields::TITLE,
                        AdCreativeFields::URL_TAGS,
                        AdCreativeFields::USE_PAGE_ACTOR_OVERRIDE,
                        AdCreativeFields::VIDEO_ID,
                        AdCreativeFields::CALL_TO_ACTION,
                        AdCreativeFields::DYNAMIC_AD_VOICE,
                        AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_FILE
                    ), array($creativeParams));
                    foreach ($creativeCursor as $adCreative) {
                        Log::info("Ad Account Id: " . $fbAccountId . " AdSet Id: " . $ad->adset_id . " STATUS: " . $ad->status . " E STATUS: " . $ad->effective_status . " Ad Id: " . $ad->id . " Ad Name: " . $ad->name . " Ad Creative Id: " . $adCreative->id . " Url Tags: " . $adCreative->url_tags);
                        if ($this->isValidCampaignObject($ad->adset_id)){
                            if (isset($adCreative->{ AdCreativeFields::URL_TAGS })) {
                                if ($adCreative->{AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC} == null ){
                                    parse_str($adCreative->url_tags, $urlTagArray);
                                    if (!array_key_exists('asid', $urlTagArray)) {
                                        $updateCount++;
                                        $urlTagArray['asid'] = $ad->adset_id;
                                        ksort($urlTagArray);
                                        $adCreative->{ AdCreativeFields::URL_TAGS } = http_build_query($urlTagArray);
                                        ksort($urlTagArray);

                                        parse_str($adCreative->url_tags, $urlTagArray);
                                        if (!$dryRun) {

                                            $this->replaceAdCreative($ad, $adCreative);
                                        }

                                    } else {
                                        $skipCount++;
                                        Log::info("Skipping [Key Exists]  " . " Ad Account Id: " . $fbAccountId . " AdSet Id: " . $ad->adset_id . " STATUS: " . $ad->status . " E STATUS: " . $ad->effective_status . " Ad Id: " . $ad->id . " Ad Name: " . $ad->name . " Ad Creative Id: " . $adCreative->id . " Url Tags: " . $adCreative->url_tags);
                                    }

                                }
                                else {
                                    $skipCount++;
                                    Log::info("Skipping [ObjectStorySpec]  " . " Ad Account Id: " . $fbAccountId . " AdSet Id: " . $ad->adset_id . " STATUS: " . $ad->status . " E STATUS: " . $ad->effective_status . " Ad Id: " . $ad->id . " Ad Name: " . $ad->name . " Ad Creative Id: " . $adCreative->id . " Url Tags: " . $adCreative->url_tags);
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                $skipCount++;
                                Log::info("Skipping [Missing URL Tag]  " . " Ad Account Id: " . $fbAccountId . " AdSet Id: " . $ad->adset_id . " STATUS: " . $ad->status . " E STATUS: " . $ad->effective_status . " Ad Id: " . $ad->id . " Ad Name: " . $ad->name . " Ad Creative Id: " . $adCreative->id . " Url Tags: " . $adCreative->url_tags);
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            $skipCount++;
                            Log::info("Skipping [Invalid Campaign Objective] " . " Ad Account Id: " . $fbAccountId . " AdSet Id: " . $ad->adset_id . " STATUS: " . $ad->status . " E STATUS: " . $ad->effective_status . " Ad Id: " . $ad->id . " Ad Name: " . $ad->name . " Ad Creative Id: " . $adCreative->id . " Url Tags: " . $adCreative->url_tags);
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $exception = $e;
            $updateCount = 0;
            $skipCount = 0;
            $attempts++;
            Log::error("Sync Ad Url Tag Error for Account[" . $fbAccountId . "] Code:" . $e->getCode() . " Message:" . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL . $e->getTraceAsString());
            Log::warning("Sleeping for " . ($attempts * 30) . " seconds...");
            sleep($attempts * 30);
            continue;
        }
    } while ($attempts < env('COMMAND_RETRY_LIMIT', 3));


    if ($attempts >= env('COMMAND_RETRY_LIMIT', 3)) {
        throw  $exception;
    }

    Log::info("Ad Account Id: " . $fbAccountId . " Updated AdSets: " . $updateCount . " Skipped AdSets: " . $skipCount);
    return (object)['updateCount' => $updateCount, 'skipCount' => $skipCount];
}
```

'replaceAdCreative' method:

```
private function replaceAdCreative($ad, $adCreative)
{

    $newAdCreative = new AdCreative(null);

    if ($adCreative->{AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC} != null ){

        $adCreativeObjectStorySpecField = null;
        if (ISSET($adCreative->{AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC}[AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::VIDEO_DATA]))
        {
            $adCreativeObjectStorySpecField = adCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::VIDEO_DATA;
        }
        else if (ISSET($adCreative->{AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC}[adCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::LINK_DATA]))
        {
            $adCreativeObjectStorySpecField = adCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::LINK_DATA;
        }
        else if (ISSET($adCreative->{AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC}[adCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::PHOTO_DATA]))
        {
            $adCreativeObjectStorySpecField = adCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::PHOTO_DATA;
        }
        else if (ISSET($adCreative->{AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC}[adCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::TEMPLATE_DATA]))
        {
            $adCreativeObjectStorySpecField = adCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::TEMPLATE_DATA;
        }

        if ($adCreativeObjectStorySpecField != null){
            if (ISSET($adCreative->{AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC}[$adCreativeObjectStorySpecField]->{AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_URL}) &&
                ISSET($adCreative->{AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC}[$adCreativeObjectStorySpecField]->{AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_HASH}))
                $adCreative->{AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC}[$adCreativeObjectStorySpecField][AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_URL] = NULL;
                //@TODO this is not working!!!^^^^
        }
    }

    $newAdCreative->setData(array(
        AdCreativeFields::ACCOUNT_ID => $ad->account_id,
        AdCreativeFields::ACTOR_ID => $adCreative->actor_id,
        AdCreativeFields::ADLABELS => $adCreative->adlabels,
        AdCreativeFields::APPLINK_TREATMENT => $adCreative->applink_treatment,
        AdCreativeFields::BODY => $adCreative->body,
        AdCreativeFields::CALL_TO_ACTION_TYPE => $adCreative->call_to_action_type,
        AdCreativeFields::EFFECTIVE_INSTAGRAM_STORY_ID => $adCreative->effective_instagram_story_id,
        AdCreativeFields::EFFECTIVE_OBJECT_STORY_ID => $adCreative->effective_object_story_id,
        AdCreativeFields::ID => $adCreative->id,
        AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_CROPS => $adCreative->image_crops,
        AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_HASH => $adCreative->image_hash,
        AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_URL => $adCreative->image_url,
        AdCreativeFields::INSTAGRAM_ACTOR_ID => $adCreative->instagram_actor_id,
        AdCreativeFields::INSTAGRAM_PERMALINK_URL => $adCreative->instagram_permalink_url,
        AdCreativeFields::INSTAGRAM_STORY_ID => $adCreative->instagram_story_id,
        AdCreativeFields::LINK_OG_ID => $adCreative->link_og_id,
        AdCreativeFields::LINK_URL => $adCreative->link_url,
        AdCreativeFields::NAME => $adCreative->name,
        AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_ID => $adCreative->object_id,
        AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_ID => $adCreative->object_story_id,
        AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC => $adCreative->object_story_spec,
        AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_TYPE => $adCreative->object_type,
        AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_URL => $adCreative->object_url,
        AdCreativeFields::PLATFORM_CUSTOMIZATIONS => $adCreative->platform_customizations,
        AdCreativeFields::PRODUCT_SET_ID => $adCreative->product_set_id,
        AdCreativeFields::STATUS => $adCreative->status,
        AdCreativeFields::TEMPLATE_URL => $adCreative->template_url,
        AdCreativeFields::TEMPLATE_URL_SPEC => $adCreative->template_url_spec,
        AdCreativeFields::THUMBNAIL_URL => $adCreative->thumbnail_url,
        AdCreativeFields::TITLE => $adCreative->title,
        AdCreativeFields::URL_TAGS => $adCreative->url_tags,
        AdCreativeFields::USE_PAGE_ACTOR_OVERRIDE => $adCreative->use_page_actor_override,
        AdCreativeFields::VIDEO_ID => $adCreative->video_id,
        AdCreativeFields::CALL_TO_ACTION => $adCreative->call_to_action,
        AdCreativeFields::DYNAMIC_AD_VOICE => $adCreative->dynamic_ad_voice,
        AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_FILE => $adCreative->image_file,
    ));
    Log::info("Old Creative Id: " . $adCreative->id . " Old Creative Creative Id: " . $adCreative->creative_id);
    $ad->creative = $newAdCreative;
    try{
        $adCreativeResponse = $ad->update();
    }
    catch (RequestException $e){
        $errorMsg = $this->requestExceptionToString($e);
        Log::error($errorMsg);
        throw new \Exception($errorMsg);
    }

    Log::info("New Creative Id: " . $adCreativeResponse->creative->id . " New Creative Creative Id: " . $adCreativeResponse->creative->creative_id);
    Log::info("Updated: " . " Ad Account Id: " . $ad->account_id . " AdSet Id: " . $ad->adset_id . " Ad Id: " . $ad->id . " Ad Name: " . $ad->name . " Ad Creative Id: " . $adCreativeResponse->creative->id . " Url Tags: " . $adCreativeResponse->creative->url_tags);


}
```